# Font icon not displaying on subdomains but works on parent domain

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, icons

## What I have:

I have a website consisting of a domain and two subdomains. My website is a WordPress multisite installation. The domain and subdomain websites each use the same WordPress theme that make extensive use of font icons.

## What I need:

I need my font icons to display on the subdomain websites instead of diplaying as...

[image]

Font icons display fine on the main domain.

## The problem:

My console log reveals:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://xxx. (Reason: CORS header
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

## My question:

Why would a website, theme and/or font icon behave differently on a subdomain than the main domain and how can resolve the matter?

Comment: Most likely, the generated (probably relative) link(s) where the font file(s) should be loaded from is/are poorly scripted and point(s) to  wrong address(es). Have you inspected your browser console? It should tell you that it's not able to load the files and you should be able to see what is wrong with the url.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You're correct. I've added the console log to my question.

Comment: You have multiple options. Either go where the script is added and add it the WP way (with `wp_enqueue_style()`) or you keep doing it wrong: go on each installation and point it to work on that particular subdomain. Or, you can declare in all your subdomain headers that they are the parent domain and cross site scripting will be allowed. :).I'd go the `wp_enqueue_style()` route. It will work on any domain, current or future, with no need to touch the code.

Comment: If you're adding your font file using `@import` in CSS (again, not recommended), change the links from absolute to relative and it should work on all (sub)domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has started in the comments of the question. Sorry about that, but I won't repeat what I said there.

Ok, so I decided to put it as an answer, as I think passing info in bits and pieces via comments is not a good practice.

And speaking of practices, here's **why** you should add all your `scripts` and `styles` using `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` in WordPress.

The key behind WordPress's success is it's flexibility. Anyone can extend or restrain it, by adding or removing functionality to/from it. In doing so, a lot of people (namely plugin or theme authors, or even the DIY guy not knowing much about web, just trying out different cool scripts he found last night) at some point decide to use a certain asset. A font library, a JavaScript library or a CSS framework.

Most of these assets, if loaded multiple times are going to conflict with themselves, especially if different versions of them are loaded. And this is why you should always tell WordPress what you are using. Because if it finds out another plugin is using the same library, it will only load the asset once and provide it for every script/plugin or whatever else needs it.

That's the main reason. One of the secondary reasons, which applies in your case, is that if you decide to move this WP to another address, it's smart enough to dynamically rebuild the urls to its assets so they work in each installation.

And i'm only scratching the surface here.

Comment: When you say "script", are you referring to font css file, the font file, functions.php or something else? The font is being loaded using font-face from a CSS file contained in the same folder as the font files. I've checked functions.php of the parent theme (no CSS enqueuing) and functions.php of the child theme (parent and child style.css is enqueued).

Comment: When I say `script` I mean what WP means by `script`: ***.js* files**. When I say `style` I mean what WP means by `style`: ***.css* files**. The fact that some of your assets load other assets internally without declaring them, is not critical if we're talking about font files, although, believe me, there aren't many font libraries compatible with other versions of themselves. It's not critical, but it doesn't make it right. Leaving theory aside, I could be of more help if you provided some actual info.

Comment: Is it as simple as deleting the font-face block and enqueuing using the correct method?

Comment: ...and does it make more sense to enqueue in the parent functions.php or the child functions.php or both?

Comment: If the faulty method is inside the parent theme, every time you update it you will have to apply this fix. I wouldn't even bother with it. I would, however, write to the theme author letting him know he's doing it wrong. By doing it inside a child theme you have complete control over it. As the change will persist even when the parent theme is updated.

Comment: I'll contact the theme author as advised and will reference your points. On the interim, I've applied the [necessary headers](http://pastebin.com/whvCd8bq) to .htaccess which has fortunately worked.

Comment: Ha, ha, I just saw who made that theme. I know Nicholas, and he knows me :). I did support for (probably) his most popular theme (Customizr) for almost two years. I won't tell you to say hi, as I'm going to write him just now, see how he's been. Nice one.

Comment: Put that pen down if you're referencing this issue. The WordPress support topic linked to in the PASTEBIN is a non-theme-specific solution. I'm not using the Hueman theme. That's the only thing I can assume you've assumed based on my non-disclosure of what theme I actually am using (unless I've overlooked something).

Comment: Oh, yes, I thought you did. And I was wondering why Nik would add an asset directly, considering his huge experience with WordPress. Something just didn't add up :). Well, I'm going to write him anyway. Now I know it's not one of his themes everything adds up.